# Creating an Excel File from a Word File in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

currently I am trying to create a macro in word that when run it looks for a few "keywords" in the document (that are essentially just titles), copy the paragraph below these keywords & then create an Excel file and paste them into separate cells in this new file, obviously saving the file once done.

Currently my code is as follows:

```
Sub WordToExcel()

Dim ObjExcel As Object, ObjWorkBook As Object, ObjWorksheet As Object

Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")
Set ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\john\Desktop\test.xlsx")
Set ObjWorksheet = ObjWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Description"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend

Do Until Left(Selection.Text, Len(Selection.Text) - 1) = "Tasks and Timeframe"
    Ctr = Ctr + 1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Loop

Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save

ObjWorkBook.Save
ObjWorkBook.Close
Set ObjWorksheet = Nothing
Set ObjWorkBook = Nothing
ObjExcel.Quit
Set ObjExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

and the word document that the macro is contained in is essentially just:

---

**Description**

Here is the general description of this document. This should be copied & pasted into the new excel file.

**Tasks and Timeframe**

Here are the tasks/the necessary timeframe. This should also be copied & pasted into the Excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** This is working for me:

(1) Remove the loop `Do Until` ........ `Loop`. The code before that already selects the paragraph you want to copy.

(2) Change

```
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

to

```
ObjWorksheet.Paste
ObjWorkBook.Save
```

Otherwise, your Word macro doesn't know which Excel sheet you are referring to.

**Result:** This is what the Excel file looks like after running the macro.

[image]

**Note:** I assume that down the road, you will want to put the sentences from the Word file into specific cells in Excel and not `A1` as your code is doing now. To accomplish that, add `ObjWorksheet.Range("B2").Select` (setting the cell to the desired target cell) before `ObjWorksheet.Paste`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.